# Use one list as multi variable, such as format argument

Tags: tcl

In Tcl

```
set f "%-3s %-3s %-3s"
set t {"aaa" "bbb" "ccc"}
puts [format $f $t]
```

I know it's incorrect, and it will return Error:

> not enough argument

So how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use [list expansion](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/%7B%2A%7D) (as from Tcl 8.5):

```
set f "%-3s %-3s %-3s"
set t {"aaa" "bbb" "ccc"}
puts [format $f {*}$t]
```

---

In prior versions, you would have to use eval, which is **not recommended**

```
puts [eval format \$f $t]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the number of specifiers and arguments to `format` is fixed, why not use [`lassign`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm):

```
% lassign $t v1 v2 v3
% puts [format $f $v1 $v2 $v3]
aaa bbb ccc
```

In general, the expansion operator `{*}` is purposeful when the number of specifiers, and, therefore, arguments is somewhat dynamic. But in the static case, you end up with a more robust script when using `lassign`. Picture your list in `t` varying in size, while `format` expects exactly three value arguments?